# php files not running in a XAMPP server

Tags: xampp

I installed XAMPP and started apache service. then i created myprograms folder inside "htdocs" and make a php program (firstphp.php) but when i open localhost/myprograms/firstphp  on a browser then it shows "object not found" 404 error.

Comment: did you added php extention  localhost/myprograms/firstphp.php

Answer (score 0):

it means that you XAMPP server is not running. You can run it by going to your start button and look for it on the previewed applications. You can also go to your XAMPP folder (default C:/xampp) the look for the xampp_start which is located below if ever your files are set in alphabetical order.